# Missing number, treated as zero

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions, subcaption

A follow-up question to this one [Aligning subcaptions with tikz pictures vertically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19822/aligning-subcaptions-with-tikz-pictures-vertically)

This is the code I am using, worked to a pretty minimal scenario:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float, tikz, subfigure, array, caption, subcaption}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\alignedsublabel}[1]{%
\node at ($(current bounding box.south west)!(#1)!(current bounding box.south east)$) [anchor=base,text depth=0pt,yshift=-3ex] {\parbox{10em}{\subcaption[]{}}};%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level/.style={sibling distance=35mm/#1}, scale=0.8]
\node [circle,draw] (z){1} 
  child {node [circle,draw] (a) {8}
    child {node [circle,draw] (b) {6}
      child {node [circle,draw] (c) {5}}
      child[draw=white] {node [circle,draw,fill=gray] (d) {9}}
    }
    child {node [circle,draw] (g) {3}}
  }
  child {node [circle,draw] (j) {7}
    child {node [circle,draw] (k) {2}}
    child {node [circle,draw] (l) {4}}
};
\alignedsublabel{z.center}{}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{This is a picture of something.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The problem is with line 26 (`\alignedsublabel`). This results in `Missing numbers, treated as zero` errors. If I take it out, everything compiles fine. I'm not exactly sure what parts of the .log file could be relevant, but this is what it says:

```
<snip>
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count132
\scratchdimen=\dimen181
\scratchbox=\box42
\nofMPsegments=\count133
\nofMParguments=\count134
\everyMPshowfont=\toks36
\MPscratchCnt=\count135
\MPscratchDim=\dimen182
\MPnumerator=\count136
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks37
) ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
Package caption Info: Begin \AtBeginDocument code.
Package caption Info: End \AtBeginDocument code.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \caption@c@figure 
l.30 \alignedsublabel{z.center}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   \caption@c@figure 
l.30 \alignedsublabel{z.center}

I was expecting to see `<', `=', or `>'. Didn't.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \caption@c@figure 
l.30 \alignedsublabel{z.center}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

[1
Non-PDF special ignored!{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}

]
<snip>
```

Any ideas? Please let me know if anything else in the .log file could be helpful as well, I only thought this would be the most relevant piece of information.

Comment: If you remove the `subfigure` package, the code compiles fine. I think this is a conflict between `subcaption` and `subfigure` (it is frequently recommended to use `subfig` instead of `subfigure`, by the way).

Comment: Sorry, seems like I was too hasty to post a question. Since I'm a newbie with latex, I do not why it was so, but seems like it didn't like the subfigure-package. In my "real document" I was using a latex class which included it... So, problem solved it seems. @Jake Indeed, thanks :)

Comment: @Rask: Welcome to tex.sx! Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While it might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of a lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you. A tip: you can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.

Comment: @Jake: Could you make your comment into an answer. So that this doesn't stay on the unanswered list.

Comment: @Caramdir: Shouldn't this really be deleted, since it's not likely that the question is useful to many other people?

Comment: @Jake: Doesn't hurt to keep this. If it is useful to one other person, its fine.

Comment: Another minor detail: Don't use `draw=white` but rather replace that line with `child {node [circle,draw,fill=gray] (d) {9} edge from parent[draw=none]}`

Answer (score 4):

If you remove the `subfigure` package, the code compiles fine. I think this is a conflict between `subcaption` and `subfigure`.

Comment: Since the OP is already using `subcaption`, there's no need to use `subfig`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I've removed the bit about `subfig`.

Answer (score 1):

Your errors should be something similar to this one:

I did the following mistake in LaTeX code:

```
$\box(p\land q)$
```

instead of

```
$\Box(p\land q)$
```

`\box` is a TeX macro defined by `\setbox`, for example:

`\setbox0=\hbox{mushroom}` defines `\box0` as `\hbox{mushroom}`, 
every time `\box0` is typed it is replaced by `\hbox{mushroom}`.

The error message refer to a digit missing, like `0` in the TeX code `\box(..` because I did a case typo, instead of the correct LaTeX macro `\Box(..`.

See *TeX for the Impatient* book, located in `plain/impatient/book.pdf` in the TeX Live documentation directory to see about TeX macros.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You can mark code by selecting the text and hitting Ctrl + K, or clicking the button marked `{}` above the textfield. This adds backticks (`\``) around inline code, or indents by four spaces for code blocks.