# Missing number treated as zero in subfigure caption

Tags: captions, subfloats, subcaption

What number am I missing the moment I want a subcaption for my subfigure it tells me I'm missing a number for some reason.   The error also disappears if I remove the roman counter option.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,UKenglish]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage{subcaption}
 \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\roman{counter}} 
\begin{document}
asdfasdf 

\begin{figure}
    \centering
   \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-grid-100x100pt}
    \caption{asdfsfad}
   \end{subfigure} 
   \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-grid-100x100pt}
   \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Caption}
   
\end{figure}


\end{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: are you using both packages `subfigure` and `subcaption` -- have a look here -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19946/missing-number-treated-as-zero?rq=1

Comment: @jsbibra  I didn't load the subfigure package though is there a way to stop it from loading?

Comment: Does your code example actually lead to the error message?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner sorry  I accidentally deleted a line   \usepackage{graphicx}  fixed now

Comment: Please make the code compilable without `pic1.png` etc, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231738. Do you know that you can format the code in your question (in the editor)?

Comment: If you don't put effort in your question then it's less likely that others put effort in trying to help.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner  how do I get code onto a new line without double spacing it?

Comment: `\par` But please make yourself familiar with "how to ask questions", at the moment **your questions have a very very low quality**. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228 and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner  I meant in the editor without changing my code it just puts all the code on one line

Comment: See https://imgur.com/a/0RVImxg

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner  I tried that but only the first line sticks and the rest falls out of that box when I paste

Comment: Please make sure that you read the pinks that I shared with you before you ask more questions.

Comment: Are you happy with the provided answer? If yes, please consider accepting it. The same is true for many of your other questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use wrong name for `subfigure` caption's number. Instead of `counter` it must be `subfigure` (see @Dr. Manuel Kuehner [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/574803/missing-number-treated-as-zero-in-subfigure-caption/574806#574806)).I guess that you like to obtain the following result:

[image]

Complete MWE is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,UKenglish]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\roman{subfigure}}
 
\usepackage{lipsum} % added for generation of dummy text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-grid-100x100pt}
\caption{first subfigure}
   \end{subfigure}
\hfil
   \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-grid-100x100pt}
\caption{second subfigure}
   \end{subfigure}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: Very good! **@HaoS** Please accept this answer.